# Can't add UITableView as subview

Tags: ios, ios5

Xcode 4.3/iOS 5.1/Storyboards.

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView in the storyboard

when initializing that view

```
    -(void) loadView {

        UITableView *tTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,60, 300, 300)
                                                               style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        [tTableView setDelegate:self];
        [tTableView setDataSource:self];
        [tTableView setBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds]];
        self.tableView = tTableView;
        self.view = tTableView;  // <--- THIS WORKS
}
```

This works, but the TableView is stretched over the entire width of the screen. I'd like it to be of a certain size as I'm using it for a login username/password control.

I was told to add it as a sub-view, but this crashes my app with some kind of recursive calling into the same "loadView" method.

```
-(void) loadView {

    UITableView *tTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,60, 300, 300)
                                                           style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [tTableView setDelegate:self];
    [tTableView setDataSource:self];
    [tTableView setBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds]];
    self.tableView = tTableView;
    [self.view. addSubview: tTableView]; // <-- THIS CRASHES

}
```

Why is this crashing? How can I add the UITableView to a subview where I can control its width and not have it occupy the entire width of my screen?

Comment: What the dot after self.view? (in   [self.view. addSubview: tTableView];)

Comment: yeah. i must have added it by mistake when typing/editing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to `self.view = tTableView` or `self.view = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame....` and then add the table view. Overriding the `loadView` method means you are going to create the `self.view`. So for your case, create an `UIView`, set it to self.view and then add your tableView as subview of `self.view`

Answer (score 0):

You use the loadView method, which means you define the view by yourself.
So self.view is not defined and the controller complains that its view is not defined when it should display itself.

Either put your interface in a xib (or storyboard) and bind those values in viewDidLoad, or instanciated the self.view by hand in loadView.